# Buying items in a list - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java

I have these 2 `List`s and `String`.

```
public static List<Items> pawnItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Items> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
public static String[][] itemsAttributes = new String[][]
        {
            {"Color TV ", "113", },
            {"Microwave ", "322",},
            {"Computer ", "1564",},
            {"Stereo ","402"}
        };
```

I have this method in which I buy products from `itemsList`.

```
System.out.println("\nWhich item do you want to buy?(type the index)\n");
choice = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();

if (choice == 1)
{
    if(budget.money < tvPrice)
    {
        System.out.println("\nYou don't have enough money");
        System.out.println("You have only: $" + budget.money);
    
    }
    else
    {
        budget.money = budget.money - tvPrice;
        System.out.println("\nYour budget now:"+ budget.money);
        itemsList.remove(0);
        pawnItemsList.add(new Items(itemsAttributes[0][0], Integer.parseInt(itemsAttributes[0][1])));
        System.out.println("\nYou bought a color TV\n");
     }
}
if (choice == 2)
{
    if(budget.money < microwavePrice)
    {
        System.out.println("\nYou don't have enough money");
        System.out.println("You have only: $" + budget.money);
    }
    else {
        budget.money = budget.money - microwavePrice;
        System.out.println("\n Your budget now:" + budget.money);
        itemsList.remove(1);
        pawnItemsList.add(new Items(itemsAttributes[1][0], Integer.parseInt(itemsAttributes[1][1])));
        System.out.println("\nYou bought a color microwave");
    }
}
if (choice == 3)
{
    if(budget.money < computerPrice)
    {
        System.out.println("\nYou don't have enough money");
        System.out.println("You have only: $" + budget.money);

    }
    else {
        budget.money = budget.money - computerPrice;
        System.out.println("\nYour budget now:" + budget.money);
        itemsList.remove(2);
        pawnItemsList.add(new Items(itemsAttributes[2][0], Integer.parseInt(itemsAttributes[2][1])));
        System.out.println("\nYou bought a computer");
    }
}
if (choice == 4)
{
    if(budget.money < stereoPrice)
    {
        System.out.println("\nYou don't have enough money");
        System.out.println("You have only: $" + budget.money);

    }
    else {
        budget.money = budget.money - stereoPrice;
        System.out.println("\nYour budget now:" + budget.money);
        itemsList.remove(3);
        pawnItemsList.add(new Items(itemsAttributes[3][0], Integer.parseInt(itemsAttributes[3][1])));
        System.out.println("\nYou bought a stereo");
    }
}
System.out.println("If you want to buy something else press 1 and if you want to go to the Pawn press 2");
choice = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
if(choice == 1)
{
    printItemsList();
    buyItems();
}
if(choice == 2)
{
    pawnItems();
}
```

And I have another method:

```
if(pawnItemsList.size() == 0)
{
    System.out.println("You don't have any items");
    pawnShopMenu();
}
else
{
    printPawnItemsList();
    
    System.out.println("You want to sell something? 1-Yes 0-No");
    int pick = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    if (pick == 1) {
        printPawnItemsList();
        System.out.println("\nWhich item do you want to sell?(type the index)");
        int choice = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
    
        pawnItemsList.remove(choice);
        itemsList.add(new Items(itemsAttributes[choice - 1][0], Integer.parseInt(itemsAttributes[choice - 1][1])));
        budget.money = budget.money + pawnItemsList.get(choice - 1).getPrice();
        System.out.println("You sold the " + pawnItemsList.get(choice - 1).getName());
        System.out.println("BUDGET=" + budget.money);
            
    }
    if (pick == 0)
    {
        pawnShopMenu();
    }
```

I got the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` when I want to sell a product in the 3rd method. I'm a beginner so I know only basic methods. When I bought an item I want to remove this from `itemsList` and add them to `pawnItemsList`. When I sell a product I want to remove them from `pawnItemsList` and add to `itemsList` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello Adelina Georgiana, welcome to StackOverflow. I think your question would be clearer if you stated what you're trying to do on the first paragraph of your question, and then repeat it on the last one. Also, a full stacktrace would be really helpful

Comment: That's a runtime error, not a compilation error, by the way

Answer (score 0):

You get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to remove something from list or array and it does not exist.
In your code before removing anything from list check if list size is greater then zero

For example:

```
 if (pick == 1) {

                    printPawnItemsList();
                    System.out.println("\nWhich item do you want to sell?(type the index)");
                    int choice = in.nextInt();
                    in.nextLine();

    //check if pawnItemsList size >0
if(pawnItemsList.size()>0)
                    pawnItemsList.remove(choice);
                    itemsList.add(new Items(itemsAttributes[choice - 1][0], Integer.parseInt(itemsAttributes[choice - 1][1])));
                    budget.money = budget.money + pawnItemsList.get(choice - 1).getPrice();
                    System.out.println("You sold the " + pawnItemsList.get(choice - 1).getName());
                    System.out.println("BUDGET=" + budget.money);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `pawnItemList.get(choize-i)` ist Not guarantied to have an entry, in fact of you skip the buying it will be empty.
If you then select 1 it will give you that error. (Nothing at Index 0 for a list with 0 entrys a.k.a News List();)

This dose not have to be the problem since i dont know how you arranged your code i am assuming that you can skip/repeat the buying process.